# How can I get the shutter speed of Android devices?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am currently developing an Android APP that requires the timestamps when the shutter is open and closed. Is there any way to get the two timestamps?

Or can I get the shutter speed of the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such information available in Android API's explicitely. The picure taken should have EXIF data, though. This data will include:

- date & time - "The date and time when the original image data was generated"
- shutter speed (also referred to as "exposure time")

Having thouse two would give you an approximation of the date when shutter has been opened and closed. Of course, for typical shutter speeds of 1/100th of a second (or less), those two timestamps will be almost the same.

Unfortunately, Android API itself doesn't allow to examine EXIF data of the picture taken unless this picture is saved to a file. See the [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) for more information. So you would need to get an image from camera, save it to a file, and then read EXIF data.

In ExifInterface, look at: [TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html#TAG_EXPOSURE_TIME) and [TAG_DATETIME](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html#TAG_DATETIME).